# liveTemplates firstWord of filename

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm, live-templates

I've two variables

```
MODULE = fileNameWithoutExtension()
COMPONENT = firstWord(MODULE) //or firstWord(fileNameWithoutExtension())
```

The my filenames are in a following pattern like

```
AccountSupervisor
UserSupervisor
TestSupervisor
```

I want the `COMPONENT` to take the first word from `fileNameWithoutExtension()` or `MODULE` as follows

```
Account
User
Test
```

**Also if someone can explain the use of "Skip if defined" option**

My attempt, it's kinda long, any better ideas.

```
capitalize(firstWord(underscoresToSpaces(snakeCase(MODULE))))
```

Answer (score 0):

`"Skip if defined"` option tells the IDE to proceed with the next input field, skipping the current one if it's value is defined using expression. For example, if you have the following template:

```
function $name$ ($args$){
    $END$;
}
```

where $name$ is defined as fileNameWithoutExtension() and `"Skip if defined"` is ON, the variable will be auto-sabstituted from the file name and you will only be prompted to enter the $args$ value; otherwise the calculated value will be focused and highlighted with red frame, and you will need to hit Enter to confirm the value and move to the next input field